# No matching distribution found for scs==2.1.4

Tags: python, numpy, pip, anaconda

I'm using conda 4.10.3 on Windows 10 64bit.

I'm trying to create a conda environment with these two files: [ml4t.yml](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Machine-Learning-for-Algorithmic-Trading-Second-Edition/blob/master/installation/windows/ml4t.yml) and [ml4t-base.yml](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Machine-Learning-for-Algorithmic-Trading-Second-Edition/blob/master/installation/ml4t-base.yml).

First, I have tried with:

`mamba env create -f installation/windows/ml4t.yml`

**I get an error**, so I have tried with:

`mamba env create -f installation/ml4t-base.yml`

The first file, `ml4t.yml`, is to create the environment with the latest versions of the libraries used in the notebooks (as of April 2021).

The second file, `ml4t-base.yml`, is to create the environment  with the latest library versions as of whenever you read this.

You can find more information about installation [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Machine-Learning-for-Algorithmic-Trading-Second-Edition/tree/master/installation).

On both cases I have an error with `pip` and `scs` package.

With the first one file, `ml4t.yml`, I get this error message:

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for scs==2.1.4

And with the second one I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scs
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\liber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j5wtb8f1\\scs_401115d47d5d45089d65831a3a0a65f4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\liber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j5wtb8f1\\scs_401115d47d5d45089d65831a3a0a65f4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5xnj3hxm\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\Include\scs'
         cwd: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j5wtb8f1\scs_401115d47d5d45089d65831a3a0a65f4\
    Complete output (27 lines):
    Namespace(blas64=False, extraverbose=False, float32=False, gpu=False, int32=False, openmp=False, root_dir='./', scs=False)
    using blas_opt / lapack_opt
    blas_opt / lapack_opt install failed, trying blas / lapack
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    copying scs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    running build_ext
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    building '_scs_direct' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\linsys
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\linsys\direct
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\linsys\direct\external
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYTHON -DCTRLC=1 -DCOPYAMATRIX -DDLONG=1 -I./ -I./include -ID:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I./linsys -I./linsys/direct/ -I./linsys/direct/external/ -ID:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\include -ID:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\include /Tcscsmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\scsmodule.obj -O3
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    building '_scs_direct' extension
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYTHON -DCTRLC=1 -DCOPYAMATRIX -DDLONG=1 -I./ -I./include -ID:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I./linsys -I./linsys/direct/ -I./linsys/direct/external/ -ID:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\include -ID:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\include /Tcscsmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\scsmodule.obj -O3
    error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DPYTHON -DCTRLC=1 -DCOPYAMATRIX -DDLONG=1 -I./ -I./include -ID:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -I./linsys -I./linsys/direct/ -I./linsys/direct/external/ -ID:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\include -ID:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\include /Tcscsmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\scsmodule.obj -O3" failed with exit status 127
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\liber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j5wtb8f1\\scs_401115d47d5d45089d65831a3a0a65f4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\liber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-j5wtb8f1\\scs_401115d47d5d45089d65831a3a0a65f4\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5xnj3hxm\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\ml4t\Include\scs' Check the logs for full command output.

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

You can find the full output in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Hv20CJfg).

It seems that there is compatibility error between `numpy` version and `scs`, as you can see [here](https://github.com/bodono/scs-python/issues/33):

> Currently, installing SCS requires numpy<1.20 to be installed.

I have tried to change the numpy version in the first file, `ml4t.yml` to `- numpy=1.19.5` but I still get the same error.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why not install `scs` from Conda? That way it's precompiled and you don't have to bother with any of this.

Comment: @merv Am I compiling `scs`? Because I don't what that environment files do. First, I have tried with the file `ml4t.yml`` (which, I think it doesn't compile anything), and it doesn't work, so I have tried with the file `ml4t-base.yml`.

Comment: Conda precompiles pretty much everything that needs compiling, and links most objects dynamically. Pip is mixed, but most wheels link statically, and that particular `scs` package is being compiled at installation and the error seems to involve the linker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem moving most of the pip package to install them with mamba.

I have changed the original file [ml4t.yml](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Machine-Learning-for-Algorithmic-Trading-Second-Edition/blob/master/installation/windows/ml4t.yml) letting the `pip` section as follows:

```
  - pip:
    - backtrader==1.9.76.123
    - livelossplot==0.5.4
    - pyportfolioopt==1.4.1
    - qdldl==0.1.5.post0
    - osqp==0.6.2.post0
    - pymdptoolbox==4.0b3
```

In other words, I have moved all of the packages available in conda from the `pip` section to the `dependencies` section.